Issue Installing and Using physics.sty
I am trying to install and use physics.sty to compile a .tex file that someone has given me. However, I'm running into issues because as per what I can see, I have installed the physics package, but I get errors when trying to compile.
Here is how I installed the package (pardon the lack of contrast in my terminal colors)

However, I get the error File 'physics.sty' not found. How can I debug this further? I'm using latexmk and the LaTeX Worskhop extension for VS Code to do compilation.
Thank you!
Edit: I can also see the physics package seemingly installed. The file /usr/local/texlive/2024basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/physics/physics.sty seems to exist!


are you sure you are using the same tex installation, in particular if you add /usr/local/texlive/bin/xxx to your path in your personal profile that may not be in scope for vscode started from a desktop menu check the log does (say) article.cls come from /usr/local or from somewhere else eg /usr/share

I believe it comes from /usr/local/texlive/bin/xxx, I'm looking in article.cls and it says "L3 programming layer <2024-09-10>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)"

@DavidCarlisle since the tlmgr package log and the article.cls agree on /usr/local/texlive, I think they should be using the same tex installation?

I actually was able to find a solution! :) Thank you for the help!

I was able to fix the issue by running sudo mktexlsr! According to ChatGPT, (so take with a grain of salt, maybe other more experienced users can comment) "[t]his will refresh the file database across all TeX directories, including /usr/local/texlive."
